# How to get a single element in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

Is it possible to just get a single element with puppeteer and not an array? I keep seeing:

`const elements = await page.$$('.some-class');`

Is it possible just to get one element without an array?

Comment: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageselector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`page.$` maps to `document.querySelector` and `page.$$` maps to `document.querySelectorAll`. If you want to get only one element you can use `page.$`:

```js
const element = await page.$('.some-class');
```